# Automatically parse JSON from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Given that current MySQL versions have JSON column types, is it possible to automatically parse JSON data when fetching results using PHP? `fetch_all` returns JSON arrays as text and does not convert them to PHP arrays, but on the other hand, numeric values are also retrieved as text.

Comment: How on earth is this a duplicate of the linked question?! Only because it's about JSON?! The linked question has nothing to do with MySQL and its JSON data type.

Comment: The JSON type is opaque to all database APIs in PHP. It still needs to be handled in userland. (Not aware if any ORMs support it meanwhile).